# QGraphicsItem selectedItems() is empty

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I'm trying to get items but I can't get to work with selectedItems(). With the following code, the qDebug returns "()" or crash of course if I use selectedItems.last().

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I even added a foreach to be sure items were selected but nothing. The following code comes from my View class.

```
 if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {


            foreach(auto item, items(event->pos())) {
               item->setSelected(true);
            }

           qDebug()<< scene->selectedItems();
```

Ask me if I can provide you further details, I have a lot of code and don't really know what could be concerned by my problem.

Moreover, if I change the foreach with :

```
 foreach(auto item, items(event->pos())) {
               scene->removeItem(item);
            }
```

the item WILL BE deleted, so it kinda select the item. I don't get why setSelected(true) then selectedItems() doesn't return me items.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that my item wasn't selectable by default. It's a QGraphicsEllipseItem by the way.

My selectedItems is working with the following flag :

```
 item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
```

Final code :

```
foreach(auto item, items(event->pos())) {

                item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
                  item->setSelected(true);

            }
```